# Passing value using ajax from one php page to another

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass some values using AJAX from one php page to another but I am not able to pass it correctly. The objective is also to load the next page after passing the value to it.
But I am not able to do it and the value is not getting passed to the next php page. I get the error

> Notice: Undefined index: var1

Here is my java code of the first page

```
function next(){
    $.ajax({
         url: "next.php",
        data: { var1 : 123 },
        success: function( data ) {
            console.log( data );
        }
    }).done(function(data) { 
        $("#content").load("next.php");
    });
}
```

Here is the html code of the first page

```
<button onclick="next()">Click me</button>
<div id="content">
```

Now in my second page I am using this to get the variable

```
<?php echo $_GET['var1'];?>
```

I have tried solutions from other post in the Internet but till now not finding any solution. Hope someone gives the answer.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

By running `$('#content').load("next.php")` you are essentially loading the page again with no query parameters.  You're already getting the response of the request to next.php in your success function - it's stored in the variable `data`.  So you can just do `$('#content').html(data);` in your success function.

```
function next(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "next.php",
        data: {var1 : 123},
        success: function( data ) {
            $('#content').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Note that the success function only executes on a HTTP 200 so if you want to be really fancy you can do this:

```
function next(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "next.php",
        data: {var1 : 123},
        success: function( data ) {
            $('#content').html(data);
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("an error occurred");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes it works thanks but I want an another objective. Suppose I want to load only a specific div of the next page then how shall  I achieve it. This is the statement that I used earlier- `$("#content").load(URL+" #div_of_next_page");`

Comment: @MrinmoyMk sorry - why would you need to do that?  shouldn't next.php just return the HTML you need?

Comment: The main project which I am developing there is necessary to partially load pages using AJAX so that the whole pages doesn't get load. In my website, in every page there is 3 div common- the header div, content div and a third div. Then during loading the next page I only need to get the data of the content div. Therefore i need the said objective.

Comment: I still don't understand.  next.php should just be a file that only serves the purpose of fetching a response for using in the XHR/AJAX request.  It shouldn't be a standard page with a header, content & footer.  It should just return the content.

Comment: My main project is a music player site. To make music continuously i must only load the content so that the player part does not reloads else the music will be interrupted every time while navigating. So I am using AJAX to load the content part. Also I was using session to pass some values but now as session is same when multiple tabs are opened so there is one problem. To fix it I am trying to pass those values using AJAX.  So I need the said objective. Every pages has a header , content and player div. Hope you are getting me this time. Thanks for all your time

Answer (score 2):

Change next function code to this:

```
function next(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "next.php",
    data: {var1 : 123},
  }).done(function(data) { 
      $("#content").html(data);
  });
}
```

`.load()` in jQuery will do another Ajax request with no data argument, that's why you get the `Notice`. Also you are not inserting the data returned form the Ajax call in your content div .

Comment: Yes it works thanks but I want an another objective. Suppose I want to load only a specific div of the next page then how shall  I achieve it. This is the statement that I used earlier- `$("#content").load(URL+" #div_of_next_page");`